# A question about generating set of groups and epimorphism

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Do there exist non-isomorphic finitely generated groups, $G$ and $H$, along with epimorphisms $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ and $\psi:H\rightarrow G$, such that every generating set of these groups is an image of a generating set, that's mean, for every generating sets $\{g_1,\dotsc,g_m\}$ and $\{h_1,\dotsc,h_n\}$ of $G$ and $H$ respectively, there are generating sets $\{y_1,\dotsc,y_m\}$ and $\{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$ such that 
$$g_i=\psi(y_i),\quad\text{and}\quad h_j=\phi(x_j)$$

Comment: The condition "every generating subset is an image of an generating subset", for a group epimorphism, is empty, since the inverse image of any generating subset is generating. So it is enough to answer the first part of the question. Take Abels's group as in my answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59209/hopfian-property, but with $F_p$ replaced by $Z=\mathbf{Z}$. Killing the central $Z[t]$ yields an isomorphic group. The intermediate quotient $2t^{-1}Z\oplus Z[t]$ yields an intermediate quotient which is not isomorphic to the original group with epimorphisms in both directions.

Comment: Your "that's mean" is not correct: "every generating set of these group is an image of a generating set" is always true (and remains true if you add "finite"). In words, your (new) assumption is "every finite generating subset of $H$ is a *one-to-one* image of a generating subset of $G$ and vice versa". Anyway my example fulfills this assumption [and even the stronger assumption that every lift of a generating subset of $H$ is a generating subset of $G$, and vice versa].

Comment: @YCor: Could you please kindly write down your groups $G$ and $H$ in details. It is very interesting for me too. But I could not follow your quick point in the above.

Comment: @YCor: Could you please make me known that if $G$ or $H$ is amenable, finitely presented and residualy finite?

Comment: In my example $G$ and $H$ are solvable (hence amenable). They are not finitely presented but I can believe this can be arranged. On the other hand residually finite is hopeless since any groups answering your question are f.g. and non-Hopfian, hence not residually finite.

Comment: @YCor: I did not understand the "The intermediate quotient $2t^{-1}Z\oplus Z[t]$", I asked groupiest in our department and have not received that's meaning. Could you please make it clear?

Comment: I mean, you mod out the matrix group by the central subgroup consisting of matrices of the form $e_{14}(x)$ where $x$ ranges over those Laurent polynomials of the form $2nt^{-1}+P$, where $n$ ranges over $\mathbf{Z}$ and $P$ ranges over $\mathbf{Z}[t]$.

Comment: @YCor: I checked the details of your example, and I found that: 1. The groups of your example are not f.g., for the central subgroup $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ could not be generated by finite elements of the groups.

Comment: @YCor: 2.If your claim is right, then groups $\mathbb Z$ and $2\mathbb Z$ also satisfied the condition, and this is absurd. 3. In the above link, we also need that $d_{ii}$ belongs to $\langle t\rangle$ instead of belonging to $Z^\times=\mathbb Z^\times\langle t\rangle$.

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan: yes, the center of a finitely generated group is not always finitely generated.

Comment: ... I don't know what you checked, but these groups are definitely finitely generated and the proof is quite standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only want to explain Yves's example in details.

Put $\mathbf Z:=\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$, the ring of Laurent polynomials. Let $B$ be a group of matrices
[\begin{pmatrix}
1&P&R\\
0&D&Q\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
]
where $P$, $Q$ and $R$ belongs to $\mathbf{Z}$, and $D\in\langle t\rangle$. The group $B$ is easily checked to be finitely generated, and its center consists of unipotent matrices with a single possibly
non-trivial element in the upper right corner. It is clearly isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$. Also, the map 
$$ \Phi:B\rightarrow B,\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&P&R\\‎
 0&D&Q\\‎
 0&0&1
  \end{pmatrix}‎\mapsto ‎‎
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1&P&tR\\‎
 0&D&tQ\\‎
 0&0&1
 \end{pmatrix}‎$$
 introduces an automorphism of $B$.

Set $N_k:=\bigoplus\{\mathbb Zt^m:m=k,k+1,\dots\}$, $k\in\mathbb Z$. The automorphism $\Phi$, implies that $B/N_k\cong B/\Phi(N_k)=B/N_{k+1}$, $k\in\mathbb Z$. Now, let $G:=B/N_0$ and $H:=B/(2\mathbb Z\oplus N_1)$. Then non-isomorphic groups $G$ and $H$ satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Oops, $\mathbf{Z}$ usually denotes $\mathbb{Z}$, I would have avoided this notation.

Comment: Yes, it works this way. $H$ is not isomorphic to $G$ because the center of $G$ is torsion-free but the center of $H$ is not.

Comment: @YCor I guess you could say $\mathbf{Z} = \mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$ (the group ring of the group $\mathbb{Z}$). :-)

Answer (score 5):

In the paper,

S. Thomas, On the concept of "largeness'' in group theory 
J. Algebra 322 (2009), no. 12, 4181–4197,

it is shown that your "bi-surjectabilty relation" between finitely generated groups is strictly more complex (in the sense of Borel reducibility) than the isomorphism relation. The proof necessarily gives uncountably many examples of bi-surjective groups which are not isomorphic.